# How do configure liquibase-maven-plugin for spring-boot and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have very typical application stack: `spring-boot:1.5.X`, `hibernate:5.X`, `maven` and `liquibase`.

There is simple to configure `liquibase` with `spring boot` without adding some configuration files especially for `liquibase`.

But I would like to create `liquibase changesets` by `hibernate entities`. I think i can do it with [liquibase-maven-plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/) and [liquibase-hibernate](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki). Also i have read [this article  about integration spring boot and liquibase](http://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app) but additional `liquibase.properties` needed there.

**My question is**: how can i configure maven-liqubase plugin without adding some configuration file, if it possible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

My config is

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <driver>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/example</url>
                <defaultSchemaName>example</defaultSchemaName>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>root</password>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.example.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                <!-- <verbose>true</verbose> -->
                <!-- <logging>debug</logging> -->
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.21.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>1.11.17.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

which is fine for any `mvn liquibase:` command except  `mvn liquibase:diff` which returns an error for me: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:diff (default-cli) on project example: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory: The application must supply JDBC connections`